# Seeking an anthology book called 'A View From A Distant Shore'

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

In the 1990s I came across a book by the title

> *A View From A Distant Shore.*

It was a collection of short stories from Eastern Europe I believe. It was an older secondhand paperback. I mostly remember a single story from the anthology. It was about the light just going out of the world. Matches eventually gave less and less light until finally no light at all.

I don't remember the names of any of the authors, the 90s were apparently a tumultuous time for me. I can't find even a reference to it online.

Comment: Hi. There's still information you can add to help, such as what language the anthology was printed in.

Comment: *View From Another Shore* messages the timeframe and structure. http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?53321 No idea if it has your story about light going away.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots one of the stories in that book, "A Modest Genius", does have a part in it about an invention that causes the whole world to become dark. It's not a major theme of the story though, just one of many wacky incidents.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Sounds like you need to post this as an answer.

Comment: Sure, why not? Now that we know one matches.

Answer (score 10):

Franz Rottensteiner's [*View From Another Shore*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?53321) contains a story entitled "A Modest Genius" by Vadim Shefner , which does cause the whole world to grow dark. It is a collection of short stories which was published in 1973, which matches your timeframe.

[image: Book Cover - "View from Another Shore"]

Here's the opening to that story:

> Sergei Kladesev was born on Vasilyevski Island, Leningrad. He was a strange boy. While other children were making sand pies and building castles, he was drawing sections of odd-looking machines on the sand. In the second grade he built a portable machine, powered by a pocket flashlight battery, which told each pupil how many good marks he would receive during the coming week. Grown-ups considered the machine uneducational and took it away from him.

I found that title by searching ISFDB titles for "view from a", and then grabbing the one that had "Shore" in it. Organic Marble provided that one of the stories had a light-dimming mechanism.

> Liussa went to the window and looked out. "Sergei, what's going on?"
> she asked in astonishment. "It looks as though an eclipse is
> beginning. The whole island is in dusk and it's getting dark in the
> distance too."
>
> "It's now dark over the whole earth and even on Mars and Venus. The
> machine uses a great deal of energy."

--from "A Modest Genius" by Vadim Shefner

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.